# Rotate web view on React Native app that is portrait only

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a portrait only React Native App. My app has a web view which opens a youtube player. I want the video to rotate in full screen mode when the phone is rotated. How do i enable rotation only on this web view? Currently it stays locked on portrait